# How to I install this dependency?

Tags: dependency-management

I'm trying to install a .deb package with dpkg -i, but I get this error:

```
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of modelio-open-source4.1:
    modelio-open-source4.1 depends on libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
    Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
```

So it seems I need to install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0. So I run `sudo apt install libwebkitgtk-1.0-0`, but I get this output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libwebkitgtk-1.0-0' has no installation candidate
```

How do I fix this? I really need this installed for school, and the clock is ticking...

Comment: This looks like it might get better answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com or maybe https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com